Why does Github not use my id-token permissions, but sets other permissions correctly?
I am trying to set up Github actions to push to Pypi automatically.
However, for some reason, Github isn't setting the permissions of the token correctly. In the job logs, they show up as only:
metadata: read

However, if I include permissions for other services, such as pages: write, that does work - it's only id-token that is completely failing.
I've verified that at the project, organization, and enterprise level, the GITHUB_TOKEN permissions are set to "Read & Write" as well.
Any idea what may be causing this?
Here's the full code:
name: Publish CLI distribution to PyPI and TestPyPI

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Wheel Distribution
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: "3.11"
      - name: Install pypa/build
        run: >-
          python3 -m
          pip install
          build
          --user
      - name: Build a binary wheel and a source tarball
        run: python3 -m build
      - name: Store the distribution packages
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-package-distributions
          path: dist/

  publish-to-pypi:
    name: >-
      Publish to Production PyPi Server
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/') # only publish to PyPI on tag pushes
    needs:
      - build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: pypi-prod
      url: https://pypi.org/p/<my project>
    permissions:
      id-token: write # IMPORTANT: mandatory for trusted publishing

    steps:
      - name: Download all the dists
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-package-distributions
          path: dist/
      - name: Publish distribution to PyPI
        uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@release/v1

  github-release:
    name: >-
      Sign Distribution and upload to GitHub Release
    needs:
      - publish-to-pypi
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: write # IMPORTANT: mandatory for making GitHub Releases
      id-token: write # IMPORTANT: mandatory for sigstore

    steps:
      - name: Download all the dists
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-package-distributions
          path: dist/
      - name: Sign the dists with Sigstore
        uses: sigstore/gh-action-sigstore-python@v2.1.1
        with:
          inputs: >-
            ./dist/*.tar.gz
            ./dist/*.whl
      - name: Create GitHub Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: >-
          gh release create
          '${{ github.ref_name }}'
          --repo '${{ github.repository }}'
          --notes ""
      - name: Upload artifact signatures to GitHub Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        # Upload to GitHub Release using the `gh` CLI.
        # `dist/` contains the built packages, and the
        # sigstore-produced signatures and certificates.
        run: >-
          gh release upload
          '${{ github.ref_name }}' dist/**
          --repo '${{ github.repository }}'

  publish-to-testpypi:
    name: Publish Distribution to TestPyPI
    needs:
      - build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    environment:
      name: pypi-test
      url: https://test.pypi.org/project/<my project>/

    permissions:
      id-token: write
      pages: write

    steps:
      - name: Download all the dists
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-package-distributions
          path: dist/
      - name: Publish distribution to TestPyPI
        uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@release/v1
        with:
          repository-url: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/


According to the docs, id-token is needed for OpenID Connect, did you configure OpenID correct? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/controlling-permissions-for-github_token#:~:text=for%20Discussions.%22-,id%2Dtoken,-Fetch%20an%20OpenID

I was looking through the settings but didn’t see any values or configuration relating to OIDC - where would I find these?

You can read more about how to setup OIDC here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-for-github-actions/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#updating-your-actions-for-oidc.

@Ignoranze I've read through that doc - but I don't see anything about how to set up OIDC on the GitHub side. It contains plenty about setting up OIDC for the cloud provider, but I don't see any settings or anything that I'm missing for enabling it in Github.

GitHub may not show id-token: write under GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions if this permission is not used. Is pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish being invoked? Please provide the output produced by this action.

Github support got back to me and said the same thing - apparently, id-token doesn't show up in the logs, unlike other permissions like pages. Updating the answer.
@DeltaGeorge

This is solved. Apparently, even if an id-token is used, it still won't show up in the logs (in GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions), unlike permissions for something like Pages.
The problem was actually in my PyPi config - the .yml file name was incorrect.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
